# Cannot find the academy module in Odoo10

Tags: odoo

I am following the Odoo 10 doc for building a website and it says to install the academy module, but I can't find it !

The update list shows this error

```
https://apps.odoo.com/web/content/1443101-3f91498/web.assets_backend.js:1719
Traceback:
TypeError: Cannot read property '$el' of undefined
    at https://apps.odoo.com/web/content/1443101-3f91498/web.assets_backend.js:1719:1100
    at https://apps.odoo.com/web/content/1442937-ea2658f/web.assets_common.js:547:681
    at fire (https://apps.odoo.com/web/content/1442937-ea2658f/web.assets_common.js:541:299)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (https://apps.odoo.com/web/content/1442937-ea2658f/web.assets_common.js:546:198)
    at https://apps.odoo.com/web/content/1442937-ea2658f/web.assets_common.js:547:874
    at fire (https://apps.odoo.com/web/content/1442937-ea2658f/web.assets_common.js:541:299)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (https://apps.odoo.com/web/content/1442937-ea2658f/web.assets_common.js:546:198)
    at deferred.(anonymous function) (https://apps.odoo.com/web/content/1442937-ea2658f/web.assets_common.js:548:56)
    at fire (https://apps.odoo.com/web/content/1442937-ea2658f/web.assets_common.js:541:299)
    at Object.add [as done] (https://apps.odoo.com/web/content/1442937-ea2658f/web.assets_common.js:542:467)
```

Comment: You have error regarding '$el' is undefined. This is because you haven't declared that variable and using it directly. So it is showing undefined error. Define that as a variable.,

Answer (score 0):

This answer maybe kinda late for you but I think it will help someone else when encounter this issue.
 1. Change the command in the documentation

```
$ ./odoo-bin --addons-path addons,my-modules
```

to the following (use the full path of folder my-modules instead):

```
$ ./odoo-bin --addons-path addons,/opt/odoo/odoo-10.0/my-modules/
```

2. Go to http://localhost:8069, if you can't find the app named `academy`, then add the `debug` into the url, like this:

   `localhost:8069/web?debug#view_type...`
3. After that, click the `Update` or `Update Apps List` choice in the left-side menu, you will find your `academy` module in the app list.

   Hope this helps!

Comment: Work like a charm!